# Why can't execute GRUB command on Debian Squeeze 2.6 with GRUB already installed?

Tags: debian, grub

I installed Debian Squeeze 2.6 (on a recently bought server) with a software RAID1. During installation I installed GRUB loader (1.9 version). System boots OK with GRAB loader 
BUT right after authorization it cannot execute GRUB command (I want to copy the GRUB from the SDA to SDB). System warning right after GRUB command invocation looks as:

```
root@servername:~# grub
-bash: grub: command not found
```

How it could be? 
(GRUB already installed and no any other OS was installed at all)

Comment: Not sure if you meant something else, but there is no such thing as `Debian Squeeze 2.6`. The current version is labeled `6.0.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no binary named `grub` installed that is part of the [grub-pc](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/grub-pc/filelist) package on Debian Squeeze.

The command you would use to install the boot loader to another drive/partition is [grub-install](http://linux.die.net/man/8/grub-install).